# Compare column values

Tags: sas

I have 5 columns and want to check which columns have exact values

```
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5
1     2    2    3    1
2     3    3    2    2
2     2    2    2    2
4     5    6    7    4
```

Here column 1(num1) and last(num5) have exact same values everywhere. How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

You could transpose and then look for duplicate rows instead.

```
data have ;
 input num1-num5 ;
cards;
1  2  2  3  1
2  3  3  2  2
2  2  2  2  2
4  5  6  7  4
;
data _null_;
 call symputx('nobs',nobs);
 stop;
 set have nobs=nobs;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=tran; var num1-num5; run;
proc sort data=tran; by col1-col&nobs; run;
data want;
 set tran ;
 by col1-col&nobs;
 if not (first.col&nobs and last.col&nobs) ;
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    _NAME_    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
 1      num1       1       2       2       4
 2      num5       1       2       2       4
```